# Punto de interrupción no se activa (Spring boot v2.2.4 + Maven) en Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

He importado un proyecto API REST con spring boot (v2.2.4) + maven; en mi máquina local.

Sin embargo; al intentar ejecutar el proyecto en modo depuración; y luego, consultar un método con postman; no se activa el breakpoint; en la clase del método consultado.

Según he leído; tal vez, no debería abrir en modo depuración con Maven. Por favor su apoyo.

**[image: Punto de interrupción en método del controller (que será invocado desde postman)]**

**[image: Forma en que ejecuto el modo de depuración]**

**[image: Selecciono la segunda opción]**

**[image: Configuración interna del debug]**

**[image: Se obtiene respuesta del método desde Postman; sin embargo, no se detiene en el punto de interrupción, para hacer debug]**

**[image: NO SE ACTIVA PUNTO DE INTERRUPCIÓN]**

Comment: Creo que si depuras al arrancar con Maven, en realidad estás depurando la ejecución de Maven, no la de tu aplicación. Busca tu case inicial (la que tiene el método main) y usa Debug as Java application

Comment: Excelente @PabloLozano. Ejecuté la clase main; como me indicaste; y ya funciona correctamente la depuración. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ve a Eclipse Marketplace y busca la extención Spring Tools 4
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Yo muestro la pestaña Installed, por obvias razones (porque ya lo tengo instalado).

En el panel de Boot Dashboard se muestran las aplicaciones spring que tenés. Selecciona en la parte superior derecha del panel Debug (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B D) y ya

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Hola Manuel, te recomiendo que leas [answer]. Por favor evita el uso de palabras que no sean formales y no sumen a la respuesta.

Comment: Corregido! Gracias.